# How to show off press your website is getting?

Tags: seo, backlinks

My product has been getting some good press lately, and I'd like to link to those articles from my blog.  My concern is that Google will see this as a reciprocal link, and I'll lose any SEO benefit that the articles gave me.

Is this a valid concern?  How do you show off press that your product is getting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this article on link schemes](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=66356) *"excessive"* reciprocal links are a no-no.  However, linking back to articles that feature your product shouldn't fall under excessive.  In addition, Google tries to evaluate the quality of the links in addition to amount.  So as long as it's relevant, it shouldn't be a huge problem.  At least, it hasn't been for me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem to do this. A lot of sites use this to promote their business and site. Create a press page and put the links there. Just don't do sitewide links or something like that from your site to the press sites. If you're really Googlenoid, make the press page noindex so that Google will ignore it.